# Change the foreach loop into the LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I stuck in an easy scenario. I have a `List<string>` object, all of its items has the body of:

```
item_1_2_generatedGUID //generatedGUID is Guid.NewGuid()
```

but there may be much more numbers
`item_1_2_3_4_5_generatedGUID` etc

now, I'm wondering how to change that loop into the LINQ's query. Any ideas ?

```
  string one = "1"; //an exaplme
  string two = "2"; //an exaplme

  foreach (var item in myStringsList)
  {
      string[] splitted = item.Split(new char[] { '_' },
                                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

      if(splitted.Length >= 3)
      {
          if(splitted[1] == one && splitted[2] == two)
          {
              resultList.Add(item);
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: you can use `re-sharper` and check whether it suggests anything :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = from s in lst 
             let spl = s.Split('_')
             where spl.Length >= 3 && spl[1] = one  && spl[2] == two
             select s;
```

Comment: And the checks of the values??

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var query = from item in myStringsList
            let splitted = item.Split(new[] { '_' }, SSO.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            where splitted.Length >= 3
            where splitted[1] == one && splitted[2] == two
            select item;

var resultList = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I think splitted will be of type string... and what he wants is to check the length of the array.

Comment: @ivowiblo: `splitted` is of type `string[]`. It's the return value of `item.Split`.

Comment: @ivowiblo: Why it should be of type string? Since `Split` returns array of string, `splitted` should be array of string, isn't it ? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, because the Where extension method will apply the predicate to each item and not the collection. For instance : items.Where(x == "test"); The Length property you are using is from string and not the array result of the split.

Answer (score 2):

This is a different approach:

```
var items = myStringsList.
            Where(x => x.Substring(x.IndexOf("_")).StartsWith(one+"_"+two+"_"));
```

You probably will need to add a +1 in the IndexOf, but I'm not sure.

What it does is:

- Removes the first item (that's the substring for). In your example, it should be "1_2_3_4_5_generatedGUID"
- Checks the string starts with what you are expecting. In your example: 1_2_

Answer (score 0):

**Edited: Added the pattern for anything at the first "position"**

```
var result = items.Where(i => Regex.IsMatch(i, "^[^_]_1_2_"));
```

Comment: I don't think starts with `item_`, it's just sample.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: if that's the case, just replace item with [^_]

Comment: I don't know anything about regular expressions :) but I think it's better to edit your answer.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: you probably should learn it. The actually pattern in my original answer really does not matter to anyone who knows regular expression. It's surprise to me that there were few answers used "split" approach, which I would call it a hammer approach for this question.

Comment: This is what you mean? "^[^_]_1_2_"